# smali logging an util/collection ArrayList

Tags: java, android, logging, smali

i want to log a ArrayList that is typed as util/collection but i cant figure out what the right syntax is. For logging it directly orconverting it to string in smali.

I tried to use the iglogger but when i recompile with the iglogger inserted it throws an error saying it cant smali the iglogger.smali.

Is there a documentation for smali logging out there?I can only find it for logging a string:

```
invoke-static {v0},Landroid/util/Log;->d(Ljava/lang/String;)I
```

Thank You

Comment: Your title is completely different from your question.

Comment: wow so fast, this was an old title from a question i never posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use IGLogger, you need to invoke IGLogger's methods. Currently you're invoking Android's Log class.

If you want to keep using IGLogger, you need this:

```
invoke-static {v0}, Lcom/whatever/package/holds/iglogger;->d(Ljava/lang/String;)I # where v0 is a String. If v0 is your ArrayList you need to call toString() on it and store that result first
```

However, it really makes more sense to just use Anroid's Log class:

```
invoke-virtual {v0}, Ljava/util/ArrayList;->toString()Ljava/lang/String; # where v0 is your ArrayList

move-result-object v1

const-string/jumbo v2, "SomeTag"

invoke-static {v2, v1}, Landroid/util/Log;->d(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
```

Comment: thank you so much, and for anyone else: arraylist can be changed to collection if the type is not defined enough